# Tivoli fail to in Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, recovery, tivoli

I work with email recovery at a university.
We have Exchange 2010 and we use Tivoli as our backup/restore program.

When you do a Mailbox Restore,you specify a user's mailbox to recover and a given day on which the backup occured. After that a folder with a name in the format of TSMRDB-server-DateOfOccurence (ex. TSMRDB-EXSERVER_20120828111630) is created.
The entire database for the backup day is copied out, only to have the user's mailbox saved into a .pst file. Yes, this seems inefficient. After the .pst file is created the folder TSMRDB-EXSERVER_20120828111630 is removed. At times the process fails and the database is left dismounted (you cannot simply go to the exchange management console and mount it) and the folder not-deleted.

When you run 
`ESEUTIL /MH "M:\2010 Restores\TSMRDB-EXSERVER_20120828111630\DB3.edb"`
on the database that was created you see that the state is `Dirty Shutdown`.
In order to repair this you can say `ESEUTIL /R e02 /D "M:\2010 Restores\TSMRDB-EXSERVER_20120828111630\DB3.edb"`. However, it gives an error `Operation terminated with error -528 (JET_errMissingLogFile, Current log file missing)`. The problem is that the server is the one handling the entire process. What log file can I give it to stop asking me or is there another way to mount the database in order to remove it?

Comment: It looks like you can just `Remove-MailboxDatabase -Identity TSMRDB-EXSERVER` and then go and physically delete the folder at M:\2010 Restores\TSMRDB-EXSERVER_20120828111630

Comment: are you aware this is a programming website? Your question is obviously more geared to server admin.

Comment: would you not say that powershell and exchange powershell are not scripting languages similar to python. thanks for marking my question down before thinking. I was asking about how to use the language and i thought who smarter than the people on here. I am new to here, too, so thanks for your help.

Comment: ESEUTIL is not a "language" and has nothing to do with Powershell. Again, your question has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I realize that this might not be the best place to post but I was looking for guidance, not necessarily a critique of my question's validity. Next time, please send a link or directions as to where I should post it. Thanks

Comment: This kind of question belongs on SuperUser or ServerFault. Google them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. Use

```
Remove-MailboxDatabase -Identity TSMRDB-EXSERVER
```

and then go and physically delete the folder at `M:\2010 Restores\TSMRDB-EXSERVER_20120828111630`.